# How to pass bundleContext reference to a bean in SpringDM

Tags: java, spring, osgi

How can I pass a reference to the `BundleContext` in the bean definition xml?

Comment: You can implement [BundleContextAware](http://static.springsource.org/osgi/docs/1.0/api/org/springframework/osgi/context/BundleContextAware.html)

Comment: Yes, but I didn't want to couple the class to Spring, and so I preferred to use the reference in the definitions xml. Either way, it can also be done your way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<bean name="myBean" class="my.Class">
  <property name="bundleContext" ref="bundleContext" />
</bean>
```